# Angularjs and static files versioning

Tags: angularjs, static-files

We are developing a web app using AngularJs (ver 1.5).
My quesion is about how AngularJs (or the browser ie chrome) handles static files with its templateUrl (for directives, i.e js files) and ng-include (for html files). Do I need to add the
 **?v=somevalue** query string to these constructs or not? So for example if I have this directive constructor:

```
function AttributesCard() {

    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        templateUrl: "app/main/educationPlaces/views/educationPlaceDetails/tabs/attributesCard.directive.html",
        controller: AttributesCardController,
        controllerAs: "vm",
        scope: {
            educationPlace: "=",
            privileges: "="
        },
        bindToController: true
    };
}
```

do I need to add to the templateUrl the query string, like so?

```
templateUrl: "app/main/educationPlaces/views/educationPlaceDetails/tabs/attributesCard.directive.html?v=17.0.11.0",
```

And the same with ng-include. Do I need to add these query strings to them as well?
It might be good to know how Angular handles these things, if at all. Or maybe only thing I need to do is just update my **index.html** file to add the query strings to the refferenced .js and .css files, and that would be it.

Thanks,
ashilon

Comment: I assume this is for cache-busting, so updated files don't serve old versions. This isn't so much about how Angular uses them but how the web server / browser you are using serves the files. Angular will just do a web request for the URL and use what it's given. If you have turned caching off completely on the web server, then you probably don't need to add the version querystring. If the server caches the files for a month, then you most likely do need to add it.

Comment: Thanks Rhumborl. So does it mean i have to add the query strings everywhere a reference to html/js/css exists? In all the templateUrl, ng-include and stuff? That sounds insane.